# Is it possible to preview wordpress themes without wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, themes

Wonder if it's possible to preview a wordpress theme without wordpress is installed. Ex display a preview of the theme twenty eleven http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyeleven. I do not need backend and other functionality of wordpress, just a preview of a theme. Tested to run twenty eleven locally with xampp but get the error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\twentyeleven\index.php on line 15
```

I am also interested in if its possible to preview themes for Drupal and Joomla (have not tested it in XAMPP).

Answer (score 1):

No. There are far too many WordPress supplied functions for you to be able to do that. Included in those WordPress supplied functions are the actual queries that populate the page with data. It is almost like asking if you can use a FireFox Addon without using FireFox, or run a Windows application without Windows.

The only thing you could do would be to run the theme on a WordPress site and extract the generated HTML with something like [Httrack](http://www.httrack.com/). At least some themes have demo sites though.

I am 99% sure the same is true for Drupal or Joomla.